# How to find duplicate values after distinct count

Tags: postgresql

One piece of code:

```
select count(distinct for_id),task_text ,status  from core.vw_task_new
where code = 'willingness_assessment' and status in ('Completed','Ready') and task_text is not null and dt > '2022-07-18'
group by task_text ,status
```

gives 647 as the total count.

however the code below:

```
select count(distinct for_id)   from core.vw_task_new
where code = 'willingness_assessment' and status in ('Completed','Ready') and task_text is not null and dt > '2022-07-18'
```

gives 630 as the count

My question is, how do I get the duplicates that are causing this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

May be below query might help you:

```
    select task_text ,status,count(1)  from core.vw_task_new
    where code = 'willingness_assessment' and status in 
    ('Completed','Ready') and task_text is not null and dt > '2022-07-18'
    group by task_text ,status having count(1) > 1
```

having count(1)>1 returns all the which existed more than once with the combination mentioned in SELECT and GROUP BY clause